# What is the keyboard shortcut to insert text in Preview

Tags: preview, shortcut

I have consulted the official shortcuts documentation and browsed various other resources on `Preview` shortcuts but have not found the magical key combination. The Toolbar is singularly unhelpful in that regard: hovering over the `new Textbox` does ***not*** give a balloon reporting what is the shortcut. Bad on Apple there..

[image]

Any hints here?

Comment: You can use this nice & free little program to find the applicable keyboard shortcuts anywhere in macOS: [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

⌃⌘T (control-command-T) is the shortcut for text annotation (Tools → Annotate → Text).

Comment: How did you discover this? I'd like to peruse what other goodies might be available.

Comment: So good!! Was looking for this for quite a while